# Check for specific email address in form

Tags: django

I'm writing an application in django that needs to only allow a form to be submitted if the email address is that of a specified domain. For example is:

```
test@gmail.com
```

And doesn't allow:

```
test@hotmail.com
```

or any other domain. So how can I do this in django to see if the email address belongs to a specified domain? Should I just split the string from the email address field and do a check on the domain or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email', '')
        if email.endswith('@gmail.com'):
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError('invalid domain')
    ...
```

Comment: @SandipAgarwal: indeed, I just wanted to keep it simple to show how custom validation is handled in django forms.

Comment: not sure you need them if the only valid email address ends with `@gmail.com` - email.endswith('@gmail.com')

Comment: @Paul Ah, that's perfectly fine then. :)